# How can I render nunjucks template from controller

Tags: apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I want to render html of another module with some data to be passed. I am trying like -

```
return res.send(self.render(req, 'my-module:widget.html', { temprature: 65 }))
```

I am trying to console temprature variable in nunjucks template(like `{{apos.log(temprature)}}`), I am getting `undefined`

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object your passing to the template will be called `data` so you should have access to `data.temperature`